# How to use Sonar SCM support with a workspace root that is not a Git repository

Tags: git, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to make work the SCM support with git on my sonar project but I get an error because my workspace root is not a git repository.

Indeed I have several git repositories for a single project so my workspace root is not a git repo but the subfolders are.

I thought that the `sonar.sources` variable would do the trick but no.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't supported yet.

One solution would have to group your Git repos in a parent Git repo, declaring them as **[submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.
But [`SONARSCGIT-6`](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARSCGIT-6) shows that submodules are not yet supported in the [SonarQube SCM Git plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Git+Plugin).

Comment: thanks for the answer. so definitely not usable for me at this moment :(

Comment: @kev not with your current configuration, indeed.